# JSONP not working with Jersey and JQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jersey, jsonp

I have a RESTful server and a jQuery script calling it to get the data.
However I am not able to get the data via **jsonp**.

**Java method:-**

```
@GET  
@Path("search")
@JSONP(queryParam="callback")
@Produces({"application/x-javascript"})
public Response getAllTestData(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {  


        System.out.println("I got executed!");
        String result="{\"id\":1}";
    //return Response.status(200).entity("{ foo: 'bar' }").build();
        //return result;
        return Response.ok("{status: 'success'}").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
    }
```

**jQuery script:-**

```
$("button").click(function() {
   var surl =  "http://localhost:8080/WikiRating/engine/employee/search";
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
       url: surl,
       data: {"name": 1},
       dataType: "jsonp",
       jsonp : "callback",
       jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
       success: function(json) {
                   alert("Success");
                },
                error: function(e) {
                   alert("Error");
                }
       });
});
```

*I am using Apache Tomcat v7.0*

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WikiRating</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/engine/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I think I have set the headers too but this does't seem to work and error is fired and `alert("Error");` is executed.

Also my script is running on port 80 while the tomcat server is running on port 8080 .

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: *"CORS not working with Jersey and JQuery"* You're not using CORS at all. You're using JSONP, which has nothing whatsoever to do with CORS. JSONP and CORS both address the same issue (the SOP), but they do so in entirely different ways.

Comment: @SMA  error: function is fired when I run the script and alert("Error") is called.

Comment: Also more to CORS than one header. If using jsonp then need to send jsonp or use cors and use browser dev tools network to get more clues as to what happens with each request

Comment: @charlietfl Hi! I have added web.xml here you can have a look.

Comment: So does it work when you request `json` instead of `jsonp`? I know nothing about Jersey or what web.xml should contain in that regard

Comment: @charlietfl The fact that I can't use JSON here forced me to use JSONP in the first place as my script is running on port 80 while the tomcat server is running on port 8080

Comment: But that's why you implement CORS .... different port is considered cross origin which is the `CO` in CORS. JSONP requires different output format from server...wrapping the json in the callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116980/discussion-between-abhimanyu-shekhawat-and-charlietfl).